# Google Maps loading twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a special situation and could really use some help. I have an html builder and every time I refresh the site it adds additional script tags. This is a serious issue because I am using Google Maps API and it keeps adding the following script tag each time I refresh the page:

```
<script src="https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/9/19/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Unfortunately this is the only way I will be able to develop pages for this project. (You can imagine my frustration >.<).

Basically, if this script tag exists more than one time on the html document it raises an error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Load'` that prevents the Google Maps API from rendering my maps.

**My question:**

Is there any way I can prevent Google's API from dynamically adding this script tag, or remove it before the document has the opportunity to load it, or have the document completely ignore it? Any assistance will help me get to sleep a little earlier this morning :)

Comment: why you don't add a cookie to load the script only the first time?

Comment: I've tried this, unfortunately the additional script tag gets added anyways.

Comment: Do not use "html builders". Use Notepad instead. ;-)

Comment: I know right?! lol...Unfortunately my project is an HTML builder.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using that include.  Use the [documented include](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API):

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
 </script>
```

Where the key is an API console key and is not required and the sensor is whether you are using a position sensor or not.