# Google maps API Object has no method load (Phonegap/Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, cordova, adt

I'm using google places to get a list of cities in a phonegap app.

I was using Phonegap 2.6 and loading and running google places was fine on both android and IOS.

I've switched to Phonegap 3.3. The app works fine using IOS and I can get a list of cities using google places.

But on Android, I get the following error :

```
02-03 16:49:25.709: E/Web Console(6149): Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no     
method 'Load' at http://maps.gstatic.com/cat_js/intl/fr_fr/mapfiles/api-
3/15/9/%7Bmain,places%7D.js:50
```

I'm using the latest version of the SDK (Android 4.4.2 - API 19) and testing on a Wiko Cink+.

Here is the code which I'm using to load google places :

```
if(!GMapsloaded) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  if (document.location.protocol == 'file:') {
     script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places&sensor=true&callback=MapApiLoaded";
  } else {
     script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places&sensor=false&callback=MapApiLoaded";
  }
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Maps loading twice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282759/google-maps-loading-twice)?

Comment: That's exactly what it was about. My function was called twice. Thank you.